# Why wasn't Mahāvīra's definition of division by zero accepted?

Tags: math-history

He wrote a book (Ganita Sara Samgraha) where he defined the result of operation of division by zero

> A number remains unchanged when divided by zero.

I think this kind of makes sense.

I know that most of you will (and should) disagree with how I view this example, but lets say: You have a cake, and you are told to divide it no amount of times. Wouldn't the result be a cake that is still intact in it's original form?

To be clear, I am asking about the history behind why this definition was rejected.

Comment: If you say that when you divide a cake no times you get the whole cake then when you divide it once you get two halves so that ${1 \over 0} = 1$ but also ${1 \over 1} = 2$. No?

Comment: Informal language has to be used carefully. If you have a cake and divide it no times you are left with one piece. If you divide it once how many pieces do you have?

Comment: I see what you both are saying. Trying to describe mathematics using language seems to cause differing definitions to clash with each other. I will accept an answer that simply poses this as a clash of systems through misunderstanding of language: where 1/1 should equal either 1 or 2, but not both, leaving 1/0 to equal "undefined" or 1, and most certainly not both.

Comment: $1/0$ doesn't "equal" undefined. Saying it is undefined means it doesn't equal anything. It just doesn't exist.

Comment: @MattSamuel Thanks for clearing that up. I am not a mathematician by any means, just a curious layman so everything I say should be taken as informal speech. Thankfully you understood what I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Division can be viewed as either [quotition or partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotition_and_partition).  The expression $\text{“}6\div 2\text{''}$ can mean either

- The number of $2$s that must be added to get $6$; this is *quotition*; or
- The number that must be added $2$ times to get $6$; this is partition.

Thus
\begin{align}
6 & = \overbrace{2 + 2 + 2}^{\begin{smallmatrix} \text{3 parts,} \\  \text{each equal to 2}  \end{smallmatrix}} & & \text{quotition} \\[10pt]
6 & = \underbrace{\quad3 + 3\quad}_{\begin{smallmatrix} \text{2 parts} \\  \text{each equal to 3} \end{smallmatrix}} & & \text{partition}
\end{align}

So let's divide $6$ by $0$:
\begin{align}
6 & = \overbrace{0 + 0 + 0 + \cdots + 0 + 0 + \cdots\cdots\cdots}^\text{How many?} & & \text{quotition} \\[10pt]
6 & = \underbrace{\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad}_{\begin{smallmatrix} \text{No terms at all.} \\ \text{What number is each term?} \end{smallmatrix}} & & \text{partition}
\end{align}

One may also view it as follows
$$
(0\times\text{what?}) = 6.
$$

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that people usually don't know what division really is. You can divide by zero, but you would have to look at mathematics from a slightly different point of view. If you want to learn the secret of division by zero, check this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7E9StS-wzks&t=2s

Comment: You've posted two answers now, both containing a link to the same video. Please read [How not to be a spammer](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) in the Help Center.